# Angular compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: The template specified for component is not a string

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

```
compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: The template specified for component MyComponent is not a string
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplate (compiler.js:17416)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:19587)
    at compiler.js:25589
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at compiler.js:25588
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:25585)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25565)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:25527)
```

It happened in ionic/angular project. Any answers will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Can you please include the MyComponent Component decorator ?

Comment: It is multi-projects structed Ionic project and MyComponent is in shared components.
and I used shared module in the one project.
Here is project structure: 
- project1
- project2
-shared

Any help would be appreciated. thanks